# Mensagem no jQuery se repetindo sempre que coloco uma nova imagem

Tags: javascript, jquery

Coloquei um input type="file" e coloquei para que um jQuery limite o tamanho da imagem a ser carregada (300x300) e joguei um aviso para que caso a imagem passe desse tamanho apareça uma mensagem abaixo do input.

Quando vou upar duas imagens que passem desse tamanho a mensagem se replica varias vezes , tentei usar o jQuery.remove() mas ainda não deu certo.

```js
jQuery("#logotipo").change(function() { 
    var fr = new FileReader;
    fr.onload = function() {
        var img = new Image;
        img.onload = function() {     
            if (img.width > 300 && this.height > 200) {
                jQuery('.aviso').append("<strong>Sua imagem é maior que o permitido, imagem permitida 300x200</strong>");                           
                jQuery("#submit").attr("disabled", true); //Desabilita o botão submit
            } else {
                jQuery('.aviso').remove();
                jQuery("#submit").removeAttr("disabled"); // Habilita o botão submit
            }
        };
        img.src = fr.result;
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});
```

[Imagem do bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9GW7.png)

Answer (score -3):

Tenta contar o numero de vezes que já deu o error, tipo:

```
if (img.width > 300 && this.height > 200) {
   var countmsg = true;
   if(countmsg) {
//ele vai entrar somente uma vez
    jQuery('.aviso').append(
         "<strong>AVISO</strong>"
       );
   }
                    jQuery("#submit").attr("disabled", true); //Desabilita o botão sumbit
                    

                }
```